# How should I safely buy/sell a preorder for Bitcoin mining equipment?

Tags: trading, multi-signature, chargeback

Suppose I need to buy/sell a preorder for Bitcoin mining equipment.  What is the safest approach (for both the buyer and seller) to conduct this transaction?

Does it matter if this transaction is done over BTC vs Dollars?

I'm assuming an escrow is needed, but not sure where to find such an arbitrator.  If multisig transactions are used, I'd like to see how this would be set up.

Comment: When you say buying-selling preorders do you mean, eg if someone else pre-ordered a mining rig you would be buying and selling that contract?  Like futures trading?

Answer (score 1):

They do it all the time over at the 'Group Buys' section of the bitcointalk forum. Have a look at how they have theirs arranged.

https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?board=137.0

Answer (score 0):

If you believe in the long term value of bitcoin as a currency, I would advise purchasing in dollars... unless there is some difficulty with the seller?

Personally, I just purchased mine on Amazon. With your specific situation though, I would find others that have purchased from this seller and get their opinion.